Cox Proportional Hazard Regression Model Interaction Interpretation
I am new to using Cox proportional hazard regression models, and I have a few questions. I use R for my analysis.
First, my model is as below. The "time" indicates the time between participants' birth year and death year, and "deceased" indicates 0 = still alive, 1 = deceased. age, sex, and race are covariates, "stress" is one's degree of stress (continuous variable), and "psych" indicates one's psychological factor. I would like to look into the interaction of stress & psych on mortality.
mod_cox <- coxph(Surv(time, deceased) ~ age + sex + race + stress*psych, data = dat))

The interaction of stress*psych shows HR = .88, SE = .05, p = .04.
I would like to ask if there is a way to interpret the findings (possibly by looking into simple slopes), and how I can plot them as below.

Thank you in advance!
I tried plot_model function and ggplot.
